# Setting up ingress controller in azure kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I followed the steps mentioned in https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#azure. While the service was created I do not any specific pods being created for nginx-ingress. Am I missing something here?

Note : I am running this on azure kubernetes service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing installing the nginx ingress.

> The following Mandatory Command is required for all deployments.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

you can also use helm for that: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm